# How can I track outbound links with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, analytics-events

I currently have a WordPress website, where I would like to be able to create an Event which tracks when visitors click through to a 3rd party web page (outbound link).

At present, my website has 3 Google Analytics Tracking Codes.  Each Tracking Code looks as follows:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxx-x"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x');
setTimeout("gtag('event', 'adjusted bounce rate', {'event_label':'more than 30 sec'})",30000 );
</script>
```

As you can see, I already have an Event integrated as to track visitors who spend at least 30 seconds on the page.

I have read through this [Google Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) page, where I can see that I would need to paste in:

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

and ...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

Now I know I would need to insert the above snippets into the `header.php` files but where I am uncertain, is:

1. How could I integrate the above snippets so that they are 'assigned' to each of the 3 Google Analytics Tracking Accounts?
2. Have I understood that the `onclick` attribute is only for use with the links we want to track on the page and not part of the Analytics Snippet, within the `header.php` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure you are using the same Analytics version tracking code. In your question, the main tracking code uses [gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/?hl=en) but the event code is based on [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=en).

You should use -as it's newest- gtag.js. So, the code to use would be:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
  gtag('event', 'clic', {
    'event_category': 'saliente',
    'event_label': url,
    'transport_type': 'beacon',
    'event_callback': function(){document.location = url;}
  });
}
```

It doesn't matter where is placed this code as long as it goes after the main tracking code.

Nevertheless, in order to make it easier and avoid changing each external link, I recommend using Google Tag Manager. Here you have a [tutorial to track external links through GTM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABo-Sk1QzrQ).